# SQL DateTime Style

Tags: sql, datetime, formatting

Firstly I know there are loads of questions regarding this topic but I could not find one suited to my situation hence this question.

I need my date time field to have the style:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm'
```

Example:

```
2016-07-12 08:13:25.763
```

Currently I have:

```
'yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss.mmm'
```

Example:

```
2016-12-07 08:36:26.000
```

I have tried casting and converting etc.
Is there a quick way to get the desired styleby means of an update statement? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Date fields in SQL have no format

Comment: Do you store it as a datetime/timestamp/date - then there is no fixed format in the data itself? Or as a varchar - which you should not do?

Comment: It is stored as a DateTime

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But Jens is right: `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values are stored **without** any format. Formatting is applied by the application _displaying_ the values.

Comment: I am using SQL Server. I need uniform data that's all and I don't have time to repopulate the data so I was looking for a quick alternative.